# Where to use Post class in a real theme, title, content or parent div or article tag?

Tags: post-class, theme-review

I am extending discussion from one another article posted on the same website →
[Where should I use post_class()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/200158/where-should-i-use-post-class).

This is the portion from `content-single.php` →

[image]

Where should I put the post-class? in the h2 tag that will print the title or on the parent article tag, which has one other div,which is a sibling to h2, title class?

```
  <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
  <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
```

I browsed this link, but still, I could not get the clarity → https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/

> REQUIRED: Could not find post_class.
> See: post_class <div id="post-" >

Comment: "Where should I put the post-class?" - I would put it in the `<article>` tag. Because, 1) Normally the classes are added to the element which contains the post data like title, thumbnail and content or excerpt, and 2) That's where the core added it to (see [`content-single.php` in Twenty Twenty-One 1.4](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentytwentyone/1.4/template-parts/content/content-single.php)).

Comment: Thanks, This is the clue for the future also we must look for the default WordPress theme created by the Auttomatic company to get the clue. You can convert this to an answer.

Comment: Automattic does not create the default themes.